# Rust - Error when trying to remove struct element from vector

Tags: vector, struct, rust

A simple attempt to add print and remove elements from a vector but I'm stuck with this error and couldn't find a solution online, so posting it here.

When I try to remove the item without the type definition it gives me an error to add the type, when I do add the type , i get an error regarding `RangeBounds` , don't know what it means so might need an explanation on this.

Version 1

```
use structopt::StructOpt;


#[derive(StructOpt,Debug)]
struct CliArgs {
    action: String,
    id: String,
}

#[derive(PartialEq,Eq,Debug,Clone)]
struct Item{
    id:String,
}

fn main() -> std::result::Result<(),Box<dyn std::error::Error>>{
    let args = CliArgs::from_args();


    let mut items = vec![];


    match args.action.as_str() {
        "add" => {
                items.push(Item {id:args.id});
                println!("Added!");
                println!("{:?}",items);
        },
        "print" => {
            println!("{:?}",items);
        },
        "delete" => {
            items.drain(|x| x.id == args.id);
            println!("{:?}", items);
        }
        _ => {
            return Err("Invalid Action, actions supported are: add and delete".into());
        }
    };

    Ok(())

}
```

Version 2:

```
use structopt::StructOpt;


#[derive(StructOpt,Debug)]
struct CliArgs {
    action: String,
    id: String,
}

#[derive(PartialEq,Eq,Debug,Clone)]
struct Item{
    id:String,
}

fn main() -> std::result::Result<(),Box<dyn std::error::Error>>{
    let args = CliArgs::from_args();


    let mut items = vec![];


    match args.action.as_str() {
        "add" => {
                items.push(Item {id:args.id});
                println!("Added!");
                println!("{:?}",items);
        },
        "print" => {
            println!("{:?}",items);
        },
        "delete" => {
            items.drain(|x:Item| x.id == args.id);
            println!("{:?}", items);
        }
        _ => {
            return Err("Invalid Action, actions supported are: add and delete".into());
        }
    };

    Ok(())

}
```

The Errors I get

Version 1:

```
❯ cargo run
   Compiling workit v0.1.0 (/Users/reaper/code/workit)
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:32:26
   |
32 |             items.drain(|x| x.id == args.id);
   |                          ^ consider giving this closure parameter a type
   |
   = note: type must be known at this point

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0282`.
error: could not compile `workit`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

Version 2:

```
❯ cargo run
   Compiling workit v0.1.0 (/Users/reaper/code/workit)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `[closure@src/main.rs:32:25: 32:49 args:_]: std::ops::RangeBounds<usize>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:32:19
   |
32 |             items.drain(|x:Item| x.id == args.id);
   |                   ^^^^^ the trait `std::ops::RangeBounds<usize>` is not implemented for `[closure@src/main.rs:32:25: 32:49 args:_]`

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `workit`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

Comment: Not sure what your real intent in using a drain method. Do you want to remove all elements which match a criteria?

Comment: drain expect a range... what you do is for drain_filter

Comment: @apatniv yeah, trying to remove the element that matches the given id from the cli args

Comment: @Stargateur , understood, the reason I used drain was because most of my searching about remove an element from vector lead me to stackoverflow examples that were using drain to remove the a single number and I tried it out accordingly.

Comment: @Stargateur , tried drain_filter and since it's unstable the compiler doesn't like me anymore.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain